# Why is there delay in Dreamweaver CS6 Code Hinting?

Tags: dreamweaver, code-hinting

Surely this issue exists in all versions of Dreamweaver, but when I am typing code its like there is a delay in the code hinting, instead of being on keypress it seems to only catch up after I stop typing? I am a fast typer, but I just don't get this.

I know there is a delay setting in the Preferences -> Code Hinting -> delay
Why would you even want delay?

I am used to environments like MS that their intellisense is instantaneous on each keystroke.

Hopefully I'm not out of luck on this.

Comment: The delay completely blew it for me - the most irritating feature ever!! I bought CS6 like a good paying citizen and they gave me a program to work SLOWER in!! So I've kept to CS3! You can reduce the lag but can't get rid of it entirely! Pathetic!

Comment: @user3364730 I ended up going with JetBrains' IDE - I went down the PHPStorm route but they have all kinds of affordable solutions and products :) I know people love their Sublime editors but I feel like JetBrains is many steps ahead of Sublime - although sublime does what people want it to do and not all the extra bells and whistles so it's up to you I guess

Answer (score 0):

Delay might be useful if you use hinting only occasionally. Most of the time when I'm typing away code hinting can in the way as much as can be helpful. So delay tells DW "I'm stuck" if there's no keystroke past given time interval.

Comment: I'm guessing most people use hinting all the time because you get more work done faster. Delay = less work done. It's like playing a PC game with lag (we decided to give this game a lag incase you needed time to think about your next move)! I don't need the hinting but without it, I'd take a lot longer doing work and no doubt there would be more mistakes. This stupid feature alone stopped me from using it. What a waste! The least they could have done was have the OPTION of delay (like a simple tick box)